Spring Boot 3.1: Problem with MIME-generation - works at Spring Boot 2.7
I have a simple Spring-Boot app that generates a MIME-structure.
I do it for tests in a simple component MyComp.
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import org.slf4j.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import javax.annotation.*;    // change to jakarta.annnotation.*  if Spring Boot 3

@Component
public class MyComp
{
    @PostConstruct
    private void init () 
    {   
        try
        {
            Properties ps = new Properties ();
            Session ses = Session.getInstance (ps);
    
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage (ses);
            Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart ("related");
            
            MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart ();
        
            mbp.setContent ("abc", "application/soap+xml");
            mbp.setHeader ("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            mbp.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "inline");
            mbp.setContentID ("<mimepart_head>");
            mp.addBodyPart (mbp);
                
            mm.setContent (mp);
            mm.saveChanges ();
    
            mm.setHeader ("Content-Type", mm.getContentType () + "; start=\"mimepart_head\"");
     
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
            mm.writeTo (baos);    //!!!!!!!!!!
            System.out.println(baos.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

It works fine when I use Spring-Boot 2 (highest Spring Boot 2 number 2.7.18).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

If I change to Spring-Boot 3.1.11 it fails with an exception at line
mm.writeTo (baos);

The exceptionis about: no object DCH for MIME type application/soap+xml
Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type application/soap+xml
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:885)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:316)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1694)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:996)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:561)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:84)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:883)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:316)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1694)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1913)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1887)
    at com.example.demo.MyComp.init(MyComp.java:70)

Any idea about the reason? How can I get it run at Spring 3?

Your code is for JavaEE, whereas Spring Boot 3+ is JakaratEE. So if you don't change your code to be JakartaEE compliant it won't work. You probably had to add some additional dependencies (incompatible ones) to make it compile in the first place. Remove those dependencies, and fix the imports instead. Remove javax.mail and replace with spring-boot-starter-mail, then upgrade and fix the compilation errors (not by adding incompatible dependecies but by changing the imports).

Thanks, it did the job. Please answer and I can give credit!

When you mean Spring Boot, please write Spring Boot. Spring is currently at version 6.something, Spring 3 is ancient.

The problem is you are using incompatible libraries.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

This is a JavaEE dependency and for Spring Boot it would be better to use the spring-boot-starter-mail instead. That will pull in all necessary and compatible dependencies.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

If you move to that dependency first, your 2.7 version will still work. Now when upgrading to 3.1 (I would suggest 3.2) your code will stop compiling. Spring Boot 3 requires a move to JakartaEE from JavaEE. Meaning you need to change the javax.mail imports to jakarta.mail in your code.
